# Getting a InvalidRouteTableID.NotFound in cloud formation for resources that exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm repeatedly getting an `InvalidRouteTableID.NotFound` in cloud formation stack when running

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name sample --template-body file://aws-network.yml
```

and I have no idea why.

This is my cloudformation template `aws-network.yml`. It's pretty standard, it creates VPC, subnets, internet gateway, elastic ip address, nat gateway, route tables and associations.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
# This CloudFormation template deploys a basic VPC / Network. 
Resources:
  vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: false 
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-vpc"]]
  internetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    DependsOn: vpc
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-igw"]]
  attachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref internetGateway
  publicSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.10.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-public-a"]]
  publicSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.20.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-public-b"]]
  privateSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.30.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-private-a"]]
  privateSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.40.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-private-b"]]
  publicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-public"]]
  publicRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: attachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref publicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref internetGateway
  natGateway: # it has a cost https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt elasticIpAddress.AllocationId # gets the allocation Id from the elasticIpAddress resource
      SubnetId: !Ref publicSubnetA # only associated to a public subnet to simplify and reduce costs
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-nat"]]
  elasticIpAddress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  privateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-private"]]
  privateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref privateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NateGatewayId: !Ref natGateway
  publicSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref publicSubnetA
      RouteTableId: publicRouteTable
  publicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref publicSubnetB
      RouteTableId: publicRouteTable
  privateSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref privateSubnetA
      RouteTableId: privateRouteTable
  privateSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref privateSubnetB
      RouteTableId: privateRouteTable
```

According to the events, that shouldn't happen, as I can see in order the following:

```
2021-04-21 17:04:05 UTC+0200    privateRouteTable   
CREATE_COMPLETE -

2021-04-21 17:04:05 UTC+0200    publicRouteTable    
CREATE_COMPLETE -

2021-04-21 17:04:22 UTC+0200    privateSubnetBRouteTableAssociation 
CREATE_FAILED   The routeTable ID 'privateRouteTable' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRouteTableID.NotFound; Request ID: b51b2b9c-af12-4376-b6e4-1698624f7522; Proxy: null)

2021-04-21 17:04:22 UTC+0200    publicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation  
CREATE_FAILED   The routeTable ID 'publicRouteTable' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRouteTableID.NotFound; Request ID: 5cb26e14-13ca-4915-9973-109dd44c5b2e; Proxy: null)

2021-04-21 17:04:22 UTC+0200    attachGateway   
CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled

2021-04-21 17:04:23 UTC+0200    privateSubnetARouteTableAssociation 
CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled

2021-04-21 17:04:23 UTC+0200    publicSubnetARouteTableAssociation  
CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled

2021-04-21 17:04:23 UTC+0200    natGateway  
CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled

2021-04-21 17:04:24 UTC+0200    rubiko  
ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    The following resource(s) failed to create: [publicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation, attachGateway, privateSubnetBRouteTableAssociation, natGateway, publicSubnetARouteTableAssociation, privateSubnetARouteTableAssociation]. Rollback requested by user.
```

Any idea on why some created resources are not being found?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I forgot `!Ref` (I'll call it a day..)

This is the correct template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
# This CloudFormation template deploys a basic VPC / Network. 
Resources:
  vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: false 
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-vpc"]]
  internetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    DependsOn: vpc
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-igw"]]
  attachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref internetGateway
  publicSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.10.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-public-a"]]
  publicSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.20.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-public-b"]]
  privateSubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.30.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-private-a"]]
  privateSubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      CidrBlock: 10.0.40.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-private-b"]]
  publicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-public"]]
  publicRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: attachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref publicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref internetGateway
  natGateway: # it has a cost https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt elasticIpAddress.AllocationId # gets the allocation Id from the elasticIpAddress resource
      SubnetId: !Ref publicSubnetA # only associated to a public subnet to simplify and reduce costs
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-nat"]]
  elasticIpAddress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  privateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref vpc
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-private"]]
  privateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref privateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref natGateway
  publicSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref publicSubnetA
      RouteTableId: !Ref publicRouteTable
  publicSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref publicSubnetB
      RouteTableId: !Ref publicRouteTable
  privateSubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref privateSubnetA
      RouteTableId: !Ref privateRouteTable
  privateSubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref privateSubnetB
      RouteTableId: !Ref privateRouteTable
```

All credit to Mike Atkinson!